Do i need wali to marry if my parents dont approve as the suitor i suggested doesnt come to their liking due to different ethnicity , revert muslim an
As female I know I need approval from my parents to marry someone but I have someone I want to marry and he is revert muslim and still learning about the religious and I am scared to tell my parents they will never approve of it, because they want me to marry someone from same ethnic group and someone with university degree, also younger than me by 3 yrs. My dad sending proposal to a suitor without asking me if I like them or not, and I am afraid that if I suggest them about the person I want to marry they will try to forcefully marry me with someone, I don't want to be miserable so I was wondering if its possible to marry without your parents approval, and is the marrige will be valid without wali? As I have no one that could be wali, and can I do nikkah without my parents like secretly then tell them about it later?
